# How to escape special symbols or special character in Java?

Tags: java, json, special-characters, java-ee-5

I am trying to pass the string value **LISBøA** in java. I works fine for me when I run in net beans IDE it gives the out put value as **LISBøA**. when build the code and try to run in console window the string value is becomes **LISB?A**. Here the special character is converted into question mark symbol. How can I eacape from this issue.

Comment: I think this is more an issue about character encoding than escaping characters

Comment: Your Terminal has a character encoding setting. You should set this to something like UTF-8. If your Java-App expects UTF-8 it should work